# how i can scan file in unix?

Tags: unix, ibm, aix, anti-virus

group of person will upload file to IBM-AIX server (OS = UNIX) and we want to scan this files .... and we have another server (OS = WINDOWS) and we install in this server kaspersky ... now :-
1. how i can scan files on IBM-AIX server (OS = UNIX) ? 
2.if step one not availabe how i can scan file by kaspersky on other server (OS = WINDOWS)

Comment: which version of windows is the server ?

Comment: Windows 2003 ....

Comment: Its impossible to answer this question properly without knowing what protocol / server software is used to "upload file"

Comment: we use HTTP protocol ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use clamav as a file scanner? aix packages: http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/packages/packages-other/